# error 1292 mysql with date camp null

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have a problem with mysql

I have this table in a DB...
[image]

I have highlighted the camp part_nascita.

In my application there is a moment that in this camp come a null value...
And arrive an error: invalid datetime format

This is the html part where is an input type=text..

```html
<div class="form-row divisoreMod">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <input type="text" id="nascitaPartNuovo" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci la data di nascita">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <input type="text" id="nascitaCittaPartNuovo" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci la città di nascita">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

When I click to a modal final button (this input is part of a mega-modal) I call a jQuery function with ajax method...this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#pulsanteNuovoDatiPart', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var dati = new FormData();
    var dataNasci= $("#nascitaPartNuovo").val();
    var dataNascitaFinale = modificaDataJs(dataNasci);
    var dataArru=$("#arruolamentoPartNuovo").val();
    var dataArruolamentoFinale = modificaDataJs(dataArru);
    var dataConge=$("#congedoPartNuovo").val();
    var dataCongedoFinale=modificaDataJs(dataConge);
    dati.append('sezionePart',$("#sezionePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('sottoSezionePart',$("#sottosezionePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('inquadramentoPart', $("#inquadramentoPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('nomePart',$("#nomePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('cognomePart',$("#cognomePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('nomignoloPart', $("#nomignoloPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('dataNascitaPart',dataNascitaFinale);
    dati.append('provinciaPart',$("#provinciaPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('cittaNascitaPart',$("#nascitaCittaPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('nomePadrePart',$("#nomePadrePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('cognomePadrePart',$("#cognomePadrePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('nomeMadrePart',$("#nomeMadrePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('cognomeMadrePart',$("#cognomeMadrePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('domicilioPart',$("#domicilioPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('domicilioCittaPart',$("#cittaDomicilioPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('istruzionePart',$("#istruzionePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('lavoroPart',$("#lavoroPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('statoCivilePart',$("#statoCivilePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('militarePart',$("#militarePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('gradoMilitarePart',$("#gradoMilitarePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('fotoPart',$('#immaginePartNuovo')[0].files[0]);
    dati.append('altPart', $("#altPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('repartoProvenienzaPart',$("#repartoProvenienzaPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('arruolamentoPart',dataArruolamentoFinale);
    dati.append('congedoPart',dataCongedoFinale);
    dati.append('comandantePart',$("#comandantePartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('zonaOperativaPart',$("#zonaOperativaPartNuovo").val());
    dati.append('gradoMilitareRaggiuntoPart',$("#gradoMilitareRaggiuntoPartNuovo").val());
    if ($("#decedutoPartigiano").is(":checked")) {
        dati.append('decedutoPartigiano', 0);
    } else {
        dati.append('decedutoPartigiano', 1);
    }
    
    $.ajax({
            url: '../PHP/getuser.php?az=nuovoPartigiano',
            data: dati,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data){   
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .fail(function(){           
        });     
});
```

and finally..with ajax I call a php page to make an SQL function...this

```js
if($_REQUEST['az']=="nuovoPartigiano") {
        
        if (!isset($_FILES['fotoPart']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoPart']['tmp_name'])) {
           $sql="insert into partigiano (part_inquadramento, part_sezione, part_sottosezione, part_nome, part_cognome, part_nomignolo, part_padre_nome, part_padre_cognome, part_madre_nome,"
                   . "part_madre_cognome, part_citta, part_provincia, part_domicilio_citta, part_domicilio_via, part_nascita, part_deceduto, part_prof, part_istruzione, part_militare, part_reparto, part_stato_civile) VALUES ("
                   . ":part_inquadramento, :part_sezione, :part_sottosezione, :part_nome, :part_cognome, :part_nomignolo, :part_padre_nome, :part_padre_cognome, :part_madre_nome, :part_madre_cognome,"
                   . ":part_citta, :part_provincia, :part_domicilio_citta, :part_domicilio_via, :part_nascita, :part_deceduto, :part_prof, :part_istruzione, :part_militare, :part_reparto, :part_stato_civile)";
            $dbo->query($sql);
            $dbo->bind(":part_inquadramento", $_POST['inquadramentoPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_sezione", $_POST['sezionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_sottosezione", $_POST['sottoSezionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nome", $_POST['nomePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_cognome", $_POST['cognomePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nomignolo", $_POST['nomignoloPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_padre_nome", $_POST['nomePadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_padre_cognome", $_POST['cognomePadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_madre_nome", $_POST['nomeMadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_madre_cognome", $_POST['cognomeMadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_citta", $_POST['cittaNascitaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_provincia", $_POST['provinciaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_domicilio_citta", $_POST['domicilioCittaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_domicilio_via", $_POST['domicilioPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nascita", $_POST['dataNascitaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_deceduto", $_POST['decedutoPartigiano']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_prof", $_POST['lavoroPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_istruzione", $_POST['istruzionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_militare", $_POST['militarePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_reparto", $_POST['gradoMilitarePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_stato_civile", $_POST['statoCivilePart']);
            $dbo->execute();

        } else {
            
            $uploaddir = "../IMG/portfolio/partigiani/";
            $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['fotoPart']['tmp_name'];
            $userfile_name = $_FILES['fotoPart']['name'];
            $urlfoto=$uploaddir.$userfile_name;
            if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir.$userfile_name)) {
                $sql="insert into partigiano (part_inquadramento, part_sezione, part_sottosezione, part_nome, part_cognome, part_nomignolo, part_padre_nome, part_padre_cognome, part_madre_nome,"
                   . "part_madre_cognome, part_citta, part_provincia, part_domicilio_citta, part_domicilio_via, part_nascita, part_deceduto, part_prof, part_istruzione, part_militare, part_reparto, part_stato_civile,"
                        . "part_urlfoto, part_alt) VALUES ("
                   . ":part_inquadramento, :part_sezione, :part_sottosezione, :part_nome, :part_cognome, :part_nomignolo, :part_padre_nome, :part_padre_cognome, :part_madre_nome, :part_madre_cognome,"
                   . ":part_citta, :part_provincia, :part_domicilio_citta, :part_domicilio_via, :part_nascita, :part_deceduto, :part_prof, :part_istruzione, :part_militare, :part_reparto, :part_stato_civile, :part_urlfoto, :part_alt)";
            $dbo->query($sql);
            $dbo->bind(":part_inquadramento", $_POST['inquadramentoPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_sezione", $_POST['sezionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_sottosezione", $_POST['sottoSezionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nome", $_POST['nomePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_cognome", $_POST['cognomePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nomignolo", $_POST['nomignoloPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_padre_nome", $_POST['nomePadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_padre_cognome", $_POST['cognomePadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_madre_nome", $_POST['nomeMadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_madre_cognome", $_POST['cognomeMadrePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_citta", $_POST['cittaNascitaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_provincia", $_POST['provinciaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_domicilio_citta", $_POST['domicilioCittaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_domicilio_via", $_POST['domicilioPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_nascita", $_POST['dataNascitaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_deceduto", $_POST['decedutoPartigiano']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_prof", $_POST['lavoroPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_istruzione", $_POST['istruzionePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_militare", $_POST['militarePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_reparto", $_POST['gradoMilitarePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_stato_civile", $_POST['statoCivilePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":part_urlfoto", $urlfoto);
            $dbo->bind(":part_alt", $_POST['altPart']);
            $dbo->execute();

            
            }
        }
        $sql="select part_id from partigiano where part_id in (select MAX(part_id) from partigiano)";
        $dbo->query($sql);
        $part=$dbo->single();
        
        $sql="insert into atti_parti (atti_part_part_id, atti_part_reparto, atti_part_arru, atti_part_congedo, atti_part_comando, atti_part_grado, atti_part_zona) VALUES ("
                . ":atti_part_part_id, :atti_part_reparto, :atti_part_arru, :atti_part_congedo, :atti_part_comando, :atti_part_grado, :atti_part_zona)";
            $dbo->query($sql);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_part_id", $part['part_id']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_reparto", $_POST['repartoProvenienzaPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_arru", $_POST['arruolamentoPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_congedo", $_POST['congedoPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_comando", $_POST['comandantePart']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_grado", $_POST['gradoMilitareRaggiuntoPart']);
            $dbo->bind(":atti_part_zona", $_POST['zonaOperativaPart']);
            $dbo->execute();
            
        $risultati="risposta=inserito";
        echo json_encode($risultati);
        exit(); 
    }
```

can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show the code that is producing the error?

Comment: I have edited my first question with the entire code...Thank you!

Comment: That's a lot of code. My guess is you are trying to insert an empty string, which is not a valid date, nor a `NULL` value.

Comment: No. the problem is not resolved!:-(

Comment: Try to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve